# Ruby average and sum on last(n)

Tags: ruby, arrays, sum, rails-activerecord, average

```
> Player.joins(:game).order('games.scheduled_start ASC').last(5).sum(:ppg)

=> NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for #<GamePlayer:0x007ff543cd05d8> 


> Player.joins(:game).order('games.scheduled_start ASC').sum(:ppg)

=> #<BigDecimal:7ff543cebc20,'0.30115E3',18(18)>
```

So, I don't understand why `.last(n)` is breaking my ability to call `.average` and `.sum` on this collection.

**EDIT**

```
[19] pry(main)> GamePlayer.order('id desc').limit(10).map{|x| x.ppg.to_f}
  GamePlayer Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "game_players".* FROM "game_players" ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 10
=> [14.0, 0.75, 1.2, 0.0, 2.55, 1.19, 2.04, 2.0, 0.0, 24.68]

[20] pry(main)> GamePlayer.order('id desc').limit(10).average(:ppg).to_f
  (74.4ms)  SELECT AVG("game_players"."ppg") AS avg_id FROM "game_players" LIMIT 10
=> 8.943831900603671

[21] pry(main)> GamePlayer.order('id desc').limit(50).average(:ppg).to_f
  (73.4ms)  SELECT AVG("game_players"."ppg") AS avg_id FROM "game_players" LIMIT 50
=> 8.943831900603671

[22] pry(main)> GamePlayer.order('id desc').limit(50).map{|x| x.ppg.to_f}.sum/50
  GamePlayer Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "game_players".* FROM "game_players" ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 50
=> 3.649800000000001
```

Anyone have an idea what this discrepancy is about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `last(5)` (or more generally `last(n)`) is a method defined on `Array`, which means the `ActiveRecord::Relation` you've build by calling `Player.joins(:game).order('games.scheduled_start ASC')` will be evaluated to an array and then `last(5)` will be called on that resulting array.

Rails adds the ability to call `sum` on an array, but it will work differently than on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (by calling `+` on each object and the current sum, starting with `0`).

Instead you will probably want to use this:

```
players = Player.joins(:game).order('games.scheduled_start DESC').limit(5)
sum = Player.joins(:game).where(id: players).sum(:ppg)
```

Note that i've switched from `ASC` to `DESC`, as limit will always take elements from the beginning. Now `sum` will actually be translated to the corresponding SQL aggregate function, which will work on the `:ppg`-column.
The `where`-clause is needed in order to trigger a subquery, to ensure that `sum` will
only work on those players selected by `limit`.

If you however actually want to work with an Array (which will be slower), you can use this method:

```
players = Player.joins(:game).order('games.scheduled_start ASC').last(5)
# builds the sum of all ppg-values of all players selected
sum = players.sum(&:ppg)
```

But `average` will only work on an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, as it is not defined on
`Array` (not even in Rails). You can, of course, build it yourself, but again, the
`ActiveRecord::Relation` method will be faster.

Comment: I don't think you can use `limit` and `sum` this way

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `SUM` returns a single row and `LIMIT` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: it worked fine... once I had a relation object, calling `average(:ppg)` worked great.